# What does `exec 6>&1` or similar do?

Tags: linux, bash, exec

I'm migrating some software from Unix to Linux.

I have the following script; it is a trigger of a file transfer.

What do the `exec` commands do?

Will they work also on Linux?

```
#!/bin/bash
flog=/mypath/log/mylog_$8.log
pid=$$
flog_otherlog=/mypath/log/started_script_${8}_${pid}.log

exec 6>&1
exec 7>&2
exec >> $flog
exec 2>&1


exec 1>&6 
exec 2>&7

/usr/local/bin/sudo su - auser -c "/mypath/bin/started_script.sh $1 $pid $flog_otherlog $8"
```

The started script is the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
flusso=$1
pidpadre=$2
flogcurr=$3
corrid=$4
pid=$$

exec >> $flogcurr
exec 2>&1

if  [ $1 = pippo ] || [ $1 = pluto ] || [ $1 = paperino ]
    then
        fullfile=${myetlittin}/$flusso
        filename="${flusso%.*}"
        datafile=$(ls -le $fullfile  | awk '{print $6, " ", $7, " ", $9, " ", $8 }')
        dimfile=$(ls -le $fullfile  | awk '{print $5 " " }')
        aaaammgg=$(ls -E $fullfile  | awk '{print $6}'| sed 's#-##g')
        aaaamm=$(echo $aaaammgg | cut -c1-6)
        dest_dir=${myetlwarehouse}/mypath/${aaaamm}
        dest_name=${dest_dir}/${filename}_${aaaammgg}.CSV
        mkdir -p $dest_dir
        cp $fullfile $dest_name
        rc_copia=$?
fi
```

I will change `ls -le` into `ls -l --time-style="+%b %d %T %Y"` and `ls -E` into `ls -l --time-style=full-isoand` in Linux.

Comment: Note that the exec redirect syntax is not a linux thing, it's a sh / bash thing and will work the same on all bourne shell based shells.

Comment: @user10489 Thanks for the info!

Comment: BTW, the code you inherited is not great -- there are tons of places where it has quoting-related bugs, f/e. Consider running it through http://shellcheck.net/ and fixing the issues identified. And also see the "Getting Metadata On Files" section of [Why you shouldn't parse the output of `ls`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Comment: Also, note that you can combine the `exec`s; `exec 6>&1 7>&2 >>"$flag" 2>&1` (grouping related redirections into one command instead of having one per line) is more idiomatic.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: I would also replace the `if` statement as a `case`: `case $1 in pipo|pluto|paperino) ...;; esac` is arguably cleaner than three separate `test` commands.

Comment: Another note: `/usr/local/bin/sudo su - auser -c "/mypath/bin/started_script.sh $1 $pid $flog_otherlog $8" ` has some serious security problems. I would write this as two commands, one that generates a safely-escaped command to run and a second one that runs it: `printf -v args '%q ' "$1" "$pid" "$flag_otherlog" "$8"` and then `sudo su - auser -c "/mypath/bin/started_script $args"`

Comment: ...otherwise if someone passed something like `$'$(rm -rf ~)\'$(rm -rf ~)\''` (or code that downloads and runs a rootkit, or so forth) in a place where it got substituted into `$1` or `$8` or so forth, you would have a very bad day. (I don't know the context of this script, but if it handles uncontrolled content like uploaded files, that's extra dangerous).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy They are files transmitted from one office to another office of the same company. Anyway, I'll follow your advice.

Comment: (BTW, also note that there's rarely a need for `sudo su` -- `sudo` itself can do everything `su` does; in many cases, `sudo -u auser /mypath/bin/started_script.sh "$1" "$pid" "$flog_otherlog" "$8"` will be enough; in other situations one can need extra arguments to `sudo` like `-i` to get more `su`-like behavior).

Comment: BTW, to understand why someone might do this group of redirections, see the Stack Overflow question [How to undo `exec >/dev/null` in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17840322/how-to-undo-exec-dev-null-in-bash) -- it's a different thing one is keeping backups to be able to undo, but same general concept.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`exec [n]<&word` will duplicate an input file descriptor in bash.

`exec [n]>&word` will duplicate an output file descriptor in bash.

See 3.6.8 in: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html

The order of arguments can be confusing, though.

In your script:

- `exec 6>&1` creates a copy of file descriptor `1`, i.e. STDOUT, and stores it as file descriptor `6`.
- `exec 1>&6` copies `6` back unto `1`.

  It could also have been moved by appending a dash, i.e. `1<&6-` closing descriptor `6` and leaving only `1`.

In between, you'll usually find operations that write to STDOUT and STDIN, e.g. in a subshell.

Also see: [Practical use for moving file descriptors](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65000/practical-use-for-moving-file-descriptors)

Comment: it doesn't seem to matter if you use `<&` or `>&`. The documentation does say for e.g. `<&` that "If the digits in word do not specify a file descriptor open for input, a redirection error occurs", but I can't get that error. With a recent-ish devel version of Bash, `exec 9>foo.txt; exec 8<&9` works fine (and fd 8 is left open for writing only, `cat <&8` gives an error etc.)

Answer (score 6):

`exec {number x}>&{number y}` copies file descriptor X into Y.

File descriptors usage:

- 0 = stdin
- 1 = stdout
- 2 = stderr
- 3-9 = additional file descriptors

In your case, they should have been opened somewhere earlier with something like `exec 3<> /tmp/some_file` to set fd3 to to some file.

Usually, you can do exec `2>&1` in order to redirect stderr output into stdout.

Your bash example is not complete, as `$8` referrs to the eight argument given to your script, so there's definitly something we're missing here like arguments 2-7...

Comment: I think it is something set by the file transfer when it starts the trigger. The script Iposted is exactly the one that runs, I only changed the name of the paths, started scripts and logs.

Comment: Pretty sure /mypath/bin/started_script.sh uses those file descriptors later

Comment: Yes, exactly. I'll add the started_script.sh to my question in a while.

Comment: Added (the interesting part of it).

Comment: Nothing more 'interesting' in your script. No fd usage. Only stderr to stdin and log file redirection.

Comment: That's all, the rest are only echos...

Comment: or rather, `exec x>&y` copies fd y into fd x.