# Convert date format of a stat command output

Tags: linux, date, stat

With the command `stat * --format='%A %h %U %G %s %z %n'` I get:

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 myuser mygroup 131072 2021-11-12 14:52:23.495595927 +0100 myfile
```

Is it possible to have a `stat` output like the following? Note that the date is in another format.

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 myuser mygroup 131072 Nov 12 14:52:23 2021 myfile
```

This is the like the output of `ls -l`, but in [another post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/684171/what-does-exec-61-or-similar-do#comment1292682_684171) they told me not to parse the output of `ls -l myfile`, that's why I asked if it is possibile to do it with `stat`.

Comment: That is the format you would get with `ls -l myfile` . So you can just use that command.

Comment: @Garo In another post they told me not to parse the output of `ls -l myfile`: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/684171/what-does-exec-61-or-similar-do#comment1292682_684171, that's why I asked if it is possibile to do it with `stat`.

Comment: Get the timestamp as seconds from epoch, and use `date` to convert it to another format.

Comment: `date -d@$(stat yourfile --format='%Z') +"some format"` would do that

Comment: @Panki Exactly, but how to do it with the output of stat?

Comment: @Garo That one only gives the date, I need all the output of ls -l.

Comment: You convert it like this: `date --date="@$(stat -c "%Y" file)"`

Comment: @CarLaTeX No, it does : Try, for example, `"%H:%M:%S"` as `some format`

Comment: changing `ls` to `stat` won't help you with the main issue, which is filenames that can contain any character, even newline. `stat --format="%n"` happily prints the embedded newline and messes up your output. You need something like `stat --printf='%A %h %U %G %s %z %n\0'` to get an unambiguous output with a NUL separator. Or use `%N` for quoted output, if you can deal with that. Then there's also the question of why you'd want the `ls` date format anyway, since the ISO 8601 one, or just plain seconds after the epoch are far easier to parse.

Comment: @ilkkachu Because there are n following istructions that parse the ls -l in my script

Comment: "I don't want to change my code which used to parse `ls -l`" isn't valid reasoning tbh

Comment: @CarLaTeX, well, ok, but you still need to deal with the issues in https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs. Or if you decide they aren't issues, then you might as well use `ls`. It's not about what the tool is called, but about having parsable, unambiguous and issue-free output.

Comment: Absolutely this ↑ the issue is about the filenames not about `ls` as such. You can trivially create a filename containing any character except `/` or NULL - including newlines. Try `touch $'hello\nworld'; ls`. It'll break anything parsing `ls` - for example `for f in $(ls); do echo "file: $f"; done`. When you're done, remove the awkward file with `rm -i hello*world`

Comment: @Panki Not if you are not expert and you inherited things that you don't know what they do

Comment: @roaima If the problem is only the file name, it is not a problem, my files arrive from a file transfer and the names are fixed, they are only alphanumeric.

Comment: @ilkkachu I can stay with `ls`, then ^^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid you need to pipe the epoch second output into some "converter". Like

```
stat file --format='%A %h %U %G %s %Z %n' | { read A h U G s Z n; printf "%s %s %s %s %s %(%b %d %T %Y)T %s\n" $A $h $U $G $s $Z $n; }
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user 21 Dez 30 14:17:03 2021 file
```

making use of `bash`'s  `%()T` format specifier to `printf`.

Comment: This works but not only for one file, not all the files of the directory.

Comment: Use  a `while` loop, then.